# Multivariable Calculus - is this function continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{|x|sin(y^{2})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}},(x,y)\ne (0,0) & \\ 
 0 , (x,y) = (0,0)& 
\end{matrix}\right.$

is it correct to change the expression to this way $\frac{|r*cos(a)|sin(r^2sin(a)^2)}{\sqrt{r^2}}$? if so and we want to check the limit when $f$ approaches zero I used the squeeze theorem so I got that, $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{|r*cos(a)|sin(r^2sin^2)}{r}\leq \ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{r\sin(r^2sin^2)}{r} =0$ since $ -r \leq rcos(a) \leq r$

so the function is continuous ?

Comment: You have to be very careful using polar coordinates to prove continuity. Typically polars can be used to disprove continuity.

Comment: "For full points," can you please explain the last equality (i.e., that the limit equals zero)?

Comment: @peterag we finish with lim $sin(r^2sin(a)^2)$ when r goes to 0 so we get sin(0)

Answer (score 1):

for $x \neq 0$ we have
$$  \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq 1  $$
Next,
$$ \sin y^2 \leq y^2  $$
by Taylor series, obvious when $y^2 < 1$